# Jenkins would not sync OpenShift Origin secrets to be used by git clone

Tags: git, jenkins, openshift

I have OpenShift OKD 3.10 as well as Origin 3.7 running on local machine. 
I created an instance of Jenkins build server from the Jenkins (ephemeral) app in the catalog.

I then created a secret in openshift with

```
oc secrets new-basicauth gitsecret --username=avogt . 
            --password=XbHw2QCrgxpAsBjnUtsz
oc label secret gitsecret credential.sync.jenkins.openshift.io=true
oc secrets link builder gitsecret
```

and expected it to become visible within Jenkins. 
This is the job of the Jenkins OpenShift Sync Plugin, as described here

- https://github.com/openshift/jenkins-sync-plugin/blob/master/README.md
- https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.10/using_images/other_images/jenkins.html

But the new secret won't show up on Jenkins credentials page.. what did i miss?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
- update the Openshift Sync plugin (from 0.9.1 to 1.0.28) by using the Jenkins plugin management page where you can update
- it works!

[Jenkins shows the credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QhjF.png)